# relax a subset of PR2 controllers

Tags: ros, arm-controller, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After bringing up a PR2 robot, the controllers are all fixed. I wonder is there a way that I can relax one arm and  have other controllers still fixed. Anyone who knows how to do this?
Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200103/relax-a-subset-of-pr2-controllers/) by [guodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4544/guodi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-12-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can stop arm controllers using:

rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controler_manager stop l_arm_controller

A list of PR2's controller names can be show by

rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list

You can see how to use the controller manager by

rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0